# rails routes access by resource name using friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, slug, friendly-id

I have a list of cities stored in `City` table. Let's say I want to generate dynamic routes to be accessible through `resource.name`, `city.name` in this example.

I want to be able to visit `/amsterdam` or `/berlin`. How?

For info I'm using **friendly_id** gem so already have slug column if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have friendly_id set up correctly:

```
match '/cities/:name' => 'cities#show'
```

or

```
resources :cities
```

From the **Quick Start** for the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#readme) gem:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

Also:

```
# If you're adding FriendlyId to an existing app and need
# to generate slugs for an existing model, do this from the
# console, runner, or add a Rake task:

City.find_each(&:save)
```

Here is a RailsCast on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

At the **end** of your routes file, add this:

```
match '*id' => 'cities#show
```

Then in your CitiesController:

```
def show
  @city = City.find(params[:id])
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps .. but I have put together a gist on what I use in my projects.

https://gist.github.com/1908782

It mostly works for what I do as my routes file is generally quite concise.

The beauty of it is, that if you attempt to visit a path that doesn't exist, it won't hit any routes!

Just a side note, this is broken in the 4.0 release. At the time of writing this, you will need to put the following in your gemfile.

```
gem 'friendly_id', :git => 'git://github.com/norman/friendly_id.git'
```

or

```
gem 'friendly_id', :git => 'https://github.com/norman/friendly_id.git'
```

Hope this helps.